# ViewController passed as parameter is not being deinitialized (Swift)

Tags: swift, memory, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing, deinit

**Setup:**
I have a `ViewController ProblemView` and `class A`. I pass `ProblemView` to class `A`, so I can work on it. It looks like this (simplified):

```
class ProblemView: UIViewController{
    var instanceOfA = A()
    instanceOfA.passView(passedVC: self)
}

class A{
    var workOn = ProblemView()

    func passView(passedVC: ProblemView){
        workOn = passedVC
        // I noticed, if I declare a varible locally like var workOn2 = passedVC, my problem is solved - 
        // but I need the variable globally, because I don't want to pass it around within this class
    }
    func doSth(){
        // here I interact with variables of the passed ViewController
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Whenever I restart this process within the app the memory increases every single time until I get memory error.

**What I tried:** I added `deinit` to both classes. `class A` is always deinitialized but `class ProblemView` **is not** (this might be the problem?).
I also found out, that when I don't declare `workOn` globally but within the `passView` function, then it works just fine. But I need have the variable globally, because I use it within many different functions of `A`. What could be a solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: Every creation of A creates an instance of ProblemView, which creates a new instance of A, which creates a new instance of ProblemView... it's quite obvious that _this_ is your memory problem, nothing to do with deinit.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Makes sense, but why does it work when I do not declare the instance of ProblemView globally but locally within the passView function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strong references to each other.

Try to change class A:

```
weak var workOn: ProblemView?

func passView(passedVC: ProblemView){
    workOn = passedVC
    // I noticed, if I declare a varible locally like var workOn2 = passedVC, my problem is solved - 
    // but I need the variable globally, because I don't want to pass it around within this class
}
func doSth(){
    // here I interact with variables of the passed ViewController
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! This solved the problem perfectly! Got to look "weak" up ^^. Would you mind explaining why the locally declared variable (workOn2) within the passView function worked as well?